# Spritekit pause and resume SKSpriteNode's action by touchesBegan

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode with a repeated movement, let me call it RunAction A, e.g goes up - down. Now I want to make a movement, letz call it RunAction B, left - middle - right - middle, by touchesBegan.

And after finishing RunAction B, RunAction A should resume. It should start an the position, where RunAction B did start and did stop.

If I use (attention pseudo lang.)

```
 [sprite RunAction A] 
 [sprite setPaused: True]  
 [sprite RunAction B]
 [sprite setPaused: False]
```

I can see, sprite has never paused!

Is it possible, to let the sprite let resume the action where it stops before?

Thanks

Comment: [sprite runAction: A  completion:^{
                    [sprite setPaused: True]  
                }];

Comment: Sorry...but this will not save me. Let me explain it again...I have a Sprite, that's move via FollowPath/RepeatForever/RunAction in a Rect. Form A corner to B corner, from B to C, C-D and again A-B...etc. Now, if touch will be detected, sprite should stop at the current position and should start a new movement, e.g. run a arc from 0 to Pi*2 and after completing, release the first movement, begin at the last current pos, where he was stopped by touching... hope, this was clear enough... :/ please find a way! thanx and cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

    myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
    myLabel.fontSize = 65;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    NSString *myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fireflies" ofType:@"sks"];
    SKEmitterNode *myParticle = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
    [self addChild:myParticle];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVectorMake(0.0, -9);
    self.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsBody.linearDamping=0.0;

    SKSpriteNode *rectNode=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    rectNode.name=@"rect";
    rectNode.position=CGPointMake(300, 300);
    [self addChild:rectNode];
    [self moveAction];




}
-(SKAction*)groupAction:(CGPoint)points
{
    SKAction *A=[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(points.x+100, points.y+100) duration:1];
    SKAction *B=[SKAction  moveTo:CGPointMake(500, 100) duration:1];
     SKAction *C=[SKAction  moveTo:CGPointMake(100, 100) duration:1];
    SKAction *s=[SKAction sequence:@[A,B,C]];
    return s;
}
-(void)moveRect:(SKNode*)node
{
    [node runAction:[SKAction  repeatActionForever:[self groupAction:node.position]] withKey:@"moveAction"];
}
-(void)moveAction
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rect" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [self moveRect:node];
    }];
}
-(void)clearAction
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rect" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node removeActionForKey:@"moveAction"];
    }];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        if(!_stop)
        {
          [self clearAction];
            _stop=TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            [self moveAction];
            _stop=FALSE;
        }
        /*
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
        sprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation=FALSE;
        sprite.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height)];
        sprite.physicsBody.friction=0.0;
        sprite.physicsBody.linearDamping=0.0;
        sprite.physicsBody.restitution=1.0;
        sprite.xScale = 0.5;
        sprite.yScale = 0.5;
        sprite.position = location;



        [self addChild:sprite];
         */
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

check out this example i just used a single rectangle but you can use as many  object you want be sure that different action group contain a different name so its easy for you to delete and pause a action when user touch screen and apply and new group of action on another object when a action is deleted or paused.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood the principe of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

every action has a complete handler in sprite kit so you can easily get when an action is finished or completed by using below sentence

//action A completed do whatever you want's to do when action is finished

```
[sprite runAction: A  completion:^{
                    [sprite setPaused: True]  

                }];
```